# One Facebook app multiple users

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, fan-page

I'm thinking of a facebook app that fetches a website's content (already developed with my own web builder) and display in a custom facebook fan page format. Clients already using the Web builder will only have to add the App to their fan page and they have their website's content already plugged into facebook.

The problem I'm having is knowing how exactly to automate this process. I can't seem to find the "Add app to page" menu when you click the Gear Icon, and the link below gives an approach I can't be explaining to every client (video further down in the link)

http://onlinewealthpartner.com/add-facebook-application-fan-page/

My head might swirling from everything I've read so far, but I'm just easing into the facebook app development. Help/insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, your central problem is to make it as user-friendly as possible for your users to add your app to their fan pages?

Bottom line is they would need to visit the link mentioned in your tutorial:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&display=popup&next=YOUR_URL

However, since you're the one creating the Facebook Tab Application, then you would already have and could supply to your users the "app_id" and "next" parameters, so all they would need to do is click on the custom link you provide.  You could even give them a button in your web builder.  Your users would just click a button, go to this link, and pick their fan page in a drop down menu.